# Thunderbird filters (rules) don't move messages to "Local Folders"

Tags: thunderbird, email-filter

*Clarification: This question is about **the action of moving a message** to "Local Folders".  I **don't** ask how to match messages for filtering, or how to match all messages.*

I created a rule that suppose to move the messages to: "Local Folders" > Inbox

[image]

The message **was NOT moved** to the destination.

What I tried:

- The rule itself - works (I tried with another action, and the action was executed).
- I changed the destination, to use a subfolder of another account -> the message is moved there byt the filter.
- I tried to run the rule manually via the Filters dialog
- I tried to let it run automatically.  It didn't matter.
- The same action can be achieved by hand (i.e. dragging tghe message with the mouse)

Is there something special about Local Folder that messages can't be moved there via filters?

Comment: same problem for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried compact folder for each folder, than close and reopen Thunderbid. This way I resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use "match all messages" but leave the filtering field empty (it's a bug that it's enabled and you can write there).

On my setup it's actually impossible to write conditions text with "match all" flag.

Anyway I tested your rule locally and worked [TB 91.5.0-win64]

Comment: my problem is not the filtering part, but it's the "move to folder" > "Local Folders".
Either the filtered email doesn't move at all,
or it moves to some strange inaccessible location which crashes thunderbird.